# Error: dynatable is not a function (ruby on rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get [dynatable under ruby on rails](https://github.com/ricardodovalle/jquery-dynatable-rails) to work. However, I get the following error `'.dynatable is not a function'`

Here are the files

```
application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .
//= require 'jquery.dynatable'
```

duels.coffee (where the table is located)

```
jQuery ->
$('#duel_table').dynatable ->
  table: {
    defaultColumnIdStyle: 'trimDash'
  };
```

and the table inside duels controller

```
    <table  id="duel_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="column">Name</th>
      <th scope="column">€</th>
      <th scope="column"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @duels.each do |duel| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= User.find_by_id(duel.createdby).name %></td>
        <td><%= duel.euro %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', duel %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_duel_path(duel) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', duel, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Probably it is only due to the code formatting of the question, but the line `$('#duel_table').dynatable ->`  should be indented... Also you should require the dynatable file BEFORE require_tree .

Comment: thank you - before the require_tree was the thing I needed to fix